# Android deep link not opening app

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I want to open my app when the user navigates to my website. In my manifest I declared an intent filter with the scheme and host for the url but the app doesn't open when I enter the url. I heard that for chrome you need a special intent url but on the default samsung internet app it also doesn't work.

Intent filter:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="appname.appspot.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If the user navigates to appname.appspot.com it should open my app instead of navigating to the website, but it doesn't work

Comment: For testing, are you manually entering the url, or are you clicking a link?  Try emailing the link to yourself, and click on the link from the email.

Comment: I am manually entering the url, will try your suggestion now

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Does it work in Samsung Internet app?